# Twilio Gather not waiting for user input

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have a functioning Twilio workflow that pulls a twilML XML file from my server, the workflow is for an outbound call that on answer recites some text, and then gathers an acknowledgement from the recipient. The call connects and completes the initial `<Say>`, but when I trigger a  after it does not wait, or gather, the user inputted data. At the end of the `<Say>` commands inside the `<Gather>` block the call is terminted.

My XML is pretty much lifted from the example documentation:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather input="speech">
    <Say><prosody rate="slow">There is a new daytime C<break strength="x-weak" time="100ms"/>T<break strength="x-weak" time="100ms"/>A for Mid and South Essex</prosody><break/></Say>
    <Say><prosody rate="slow">There is a new daytime C<break strength="x-weak" time="100ms"/>T<break strength="x-weak" time="100ms"/>A for Mid and South Essex</prosody><break/></Say>
    <Say>Please press 1 to acknowledge.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

I can't find anything that looks like this issue in any of the documentation or on StackOverflow.

If it's relevant I am using United Kingdom numbers and have tried both from a mobile number and a fixed landline number.

Thanks in advance! It's driving me round the bend a bit.

Comment: I just tested this TwiML and it waited for the expected 5 seconds until the timeout struck. So it seems to be working. Can you describe what behavior you were expecting? Also, can you confirm that you don't get incoming requests to the action URL (which is the same URL as the TwiML if not specified)

Comment: Hey, sorry, not sure how I missed this notification. I don't get the 5 second wait, I have the speech read out, then the call goes dead.

Comment: You need to define a webhook: a url that is used by Twilio to redirect gathered input in order to be processed. You can use `action` attribute on `Gather` label to define where should input be redirected. And you can specify also `method` (GET or POST).